# Youtube emedded wont work in Firefox

Tags: flash, firefox, youtube

This does work in IE but not Firefox?

```
<object  type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLF58B42DA866233A8&showinfo=1" bgcolor="#000000" />
                        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
                        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
                        <param name="allowNetworking" value="all" />
                        <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLF58B42DA866233A8&showinfo=1" />
                    </object>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first line is self-closing

```
<object  type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLF58B42DA866233A8&showinfo=1" bgcolor="#000000" />
```

Get rid of the last slash and try again.